# js-beautify isn't correctly formatting simple html

Tags: javascript, html, js-beautify

I've installed js-beautify with npm:

```
npm -g install js-beautify
```

And I'm using a very basic one line echo to test it out.

This appears to work ok:

```
echo '<div><div></div></div>' | js-beautify --type html -s 2
// 
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>⏎
```

But this isn't:

```
echo '<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong>is awesome</h2>' | js-beautify --type html -s 2
//
<h2><strong><a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a></strong>is awesome</h2>⏎
```

Nor is this:

```
echo '<div><h2>This is awesome</h2></div>' | js-beautify --type html -s 4
//
<div>
    <h2>This is awesome</h2></div>⏎
```

What gives? I'm expecting to see something more like this:

```
<h2>
    <strong>
        <a href="http://awesome.com">AwesomeCom</a>
    </strong>
    <span>is awesome</span>
</h2>
```

Or at the very least this:

```
<div>
    <h2>This is awesome</h2>
</div>
```

Here is the html I *actually* want to format:

```
<address>
                  <strong>Twitter, Inc.</strong><br/>795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600<br/>San Francisco, CA 94107<br/><abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (123) 456-7890
                  </address>

<address>
                  <strong>Full Name</strong><br/>
                  <a href="mailto:#">first.last@example.com</a>
                </address>
```

Expecting that (per http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/) it would look like:

```
<address>
    <strong>Twitter, Inc.</strong>
    <br/>795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600
    <br/>San Francisco, CA 94107
    <br/>
    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (123) 456-7890

</address>
<address>
    <strong>Full Name</strong>
    <br/>
    <a href="mailto:#">first.last@example.com</a>
</address>
```

But js-beautify doesn't even seem to change it at all. I doing something wrong? Or is js-beautify just not that equipped to format html the way I want?

Comment: The clue is in the name right? Why would a JS beautifier change html? That would require an HTML beautifier right?

Comment: "Beautify JavaScript or HTML (ctrl-enter)". It supports html and CSS too.

Comment: Maybe the package isn't good enough. Or maybe there are configurations that need to be set?

Comment: Hence why I've asked the question here...

Comment: Yep. Imma need some bedtime snacks for this one.